# Is the solution of Poisson equation analytic?

Tags: analytic-functions, poissons-equation

I have two questions about the analyticity of solutions of Poisson equation: Let $f$ be a real-valued smooth function on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, as we know that the Poisson equation
$$\Delta u = f $$
can have many solutions (up to harmonic functions). I wonder that

1. If $f$ is analytic, is there an analytic solution for the Poisson equation in general? The reference to this question is welcome!
2. Is there an example (or proof) that if $f$ is not analytic then its solutions are not analytic?

Comment: Do you mean analytic as a function of $z = x + i y$ for $(x,y) \in \Omega$, or having an analytic extension to a region of $\mathbb C^2$ containing $\Omega$?

Comment: The second meaning of your comment is what I want to ask, i.e. $f$ has an analytic extension to a region of $\mathbb{C}^2$ containing $\Omega$.

Comment: If $u$ is analytic, then $f = \Delta u$ must also be analytic.  So if $f$ is not analytic, then $u$ can't be analytic.

Comment: You are right! The second question seems trivial! Thank you for your comment!